# Does twitterBootstrap modal stops script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap modal in my page.

Actually i want to submit a form by ajax but before submitting it i want to ask for some more user input inside modal and then wants to submit this new input along with the old form data to same url in one single submission

Comment: I'd suggest binding the submission of the form to the "yes" confirmation button on the modal, or pass the submission code into the modal via a callback.

Comment: No it won't. You can try it yourself. Showing the dialog will cause adding DOM elements to the browser.

Comment: Thankss sebastian u are right modal doesn't stop script. But how to handle this situation now

Comment: @Akshat you have lots of options. You could show the dialog within a form button and make the dialog's 'ok' button submit the form. All depends how are you wrapping out elements.

Answer (score 0):

No your script will not stop. It's just the effect that you think it will have a pause but it doesn't it only show your modal that's all.

But having an ajax call with async to true your script will be paused and let the ajax call run and when finished it will resume your other running scripts.

Now If I remember correctly ajax async is deprecated in version 1.8 and later so instead of using async we should now use callbacks in ajax.

Comment: Thanks @Drixson for your answer. But i am unable to use callbacks in this case due to some reasons. In my case modal is getting displayed only once the ajax request gets started i.e. i am displaying modal in ajax:beforeSend event. So i want to pause ajax request in this stage and only restart once i submit form in modal

Comment: No problem , but I believe it's much better to use callback functions in ajax for example `.beforeSend()` you can put any event there before the ajax call best regards to your work